# How to get Content of Remote page Via PHP

Tags: php

i used `"Simple_html_dom.php"` To Get Content.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.zone-h.com/archive/notifier=Mr.GTz');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

i test it on some urls and get result .example google.com but i set this url  `"http://www.zone-h.com/archive/notifier=Mr.GTz"` to get contents but return empty result. 
how i can Get Contents from this Site?

```
http://www.zone-h.com
```

Comment: Well when hitting it in a web browser, it did a redirect and it became http://www.zone-h.com/archive/notifier=Mr.GTz?zh=1, so try that.

Comment: zh=1 is redirect you to 2, and so on. There are always 2 or more redirects. Use CURL and use follow redirections, and get the content into a string.

After that, load that string.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.zone-h.com/archive/notifier=Mr.GTz');
```

to

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.zone-h.com/archive/notifier=Mr.GTz?zh=1');
```

It's because the page does a redirect using Javascript, instead of using HTTP redirect. The good thing is you change the number at the end to get to the page in the site you want to.

For example:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.zone-h.com/archive/notifier=Mr.GTz?zh=2');
```

will take you to the second page in the listing.

Comment: file_get_html('http://www.zone-h.com/archive/notifier=Mr.GTz?zh=2  wille not take to second page .. it's just verify page parameter.